# How to search for empty strings in a text field with Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, orm, sql-like

I'd like to know how can I search for empty strings when I'm using a text type field with Entity Framework.

I've looked the SQL query that Entity is generating and It's using LIKE to compare because It's searching in a text type field, so when I use .Equals(""), == "", == string.Empty, .Contains(""), .Contains(string.Empty), and everything else, It's returning all results because it sql query is like '' and the == command throws exception because It uses the = command that is not valid with text type field.

When I try to use .Equals(null), .Contains(null), == null, It returns nothing, because It is generating FIELD ISNULL command.

I already tried the .Lenght == 0 but It throws an exception...

Comment: `where(f => f.MyField == "")` should work. Perhaps you can use the linq `Count()` function: `where(f => f.MyField.Count() == 0)`

Comment: This can't be true. `Contains` is indeed mapped to `LIKE`, but `== ""` should generate something like `N'' = [Extent1].[Field]`

Comment: Please show one example, `== string.Empty` and the generated SQL. You (or we) must be overlooking something.

Comment: Alexander, the Count() == 0 thow the exception: `DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.\r\nNome do parâmetro: input,`. I guess It's because It is a string and not a collection, I must use Lenght.  And the == "": `The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the equal to operator.`

Sorry guys, I forgot to say that the == are mapped to = in SQL Query and It throws exception with text type. I tried to hightlight that I've tried everything, and == string.Empty means equals(string.Empty).

Comment: Well, that's an important detail. The column has the deprecated data type `text`, which can't be searched. Can you change it into `nvarchar(max)`?

Comment: Unfortunately I'll have to do this. I've searched how can I do this using SQL and I found this command that works: datalength(mytextfield) = 0. This command follows the principle of .Lenght == 0, but the Entity compile It to this SQL command: `((0 = ( CAST(LEN([Extent1].[descricao]) AS int)))` that throws an `CommandExecutionException` with the message: `Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of len function.`. I've searched for solutions to this error but everyone says to change the field type to varchar(max) that is the replacement to text type. I'll try to do this.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
public class POCO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
      var pocos = new List<POCO>
      {
          new POCO { Id = 1, Name = "John", Description = "basic" },
          new POCO { Id = 2, Name = "Jane", Description = "" },
          new POCO { Id = 3, Name = "Joey", Description = string.Empty }
      };

  pocos.Where(x => x.Description == string.Empty)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Id} {x.Name} {x.Description}"));
}
```

However the issue MAY BE that your T4 generated object is not fully realized with data you can use, if you are using Entity Framework.  EG the translation from the database is not populating objects to interrogate correctly.  I would just do an operation like this to see:

```
  using (var context = new YOURCONTEXTNAME())
  {
    var persons = context.YOURDATABASEOBJECT.ToList();

    persons.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.COLUMNINQUESTION}"));
  }
```

If you are successfully having data in it, it should be retrieved.  I would not use text if possible.  Use a varchar(max) nvarchar(max) xml, whatever text will be deprecated eventually and is bad form so to speak to continue using at this point.

EDIT
Okay I see, the answer is you cannot interogate the object until it is fully realized when it is text.  I did a test on my local database and created a context and tested it and sure enough you cannot do a '== string.empty', '== ""', or 'String.IsNullOrEmpty()' on a text.  However you can do it once the object is materialized in a realized object.  EG:

```
// Won't work as context does not understand type
//var persons = context.tePersons.Where(x => x.Description == string.Empty).ToList();

//Works fine as transformation got the object translated to a string in .NET
var start = context.tePersons.ToList();
var persons = start.Where(x => x.Description == String.Empty).ToList();
```

This poses a problem obviously as you need to get ALL your data potentially before performing a predicate.  Not the best means by any measure.  You could do a sql object for this instead then to do a function, proc, or view to change this.

Comment: The OP's [comment, now 2 hours ago,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36290416/how-to-search-for-empty-strings-in-a-text-field-with-entity-framework#comment60210964_36290416) made it clear that this can't work. I already suggested the OP to move to nvarchar(max). Also, fetching all data from a table containing text (a Large Object) into memory is a bad idea.

Comment: I agree that is why I posted this: 'This poses a problem obviously as you need to get ALL your data potentially before performing a predicate. Not the best means by any measure. You could do a sql object for this instead then to do a function, proc, or view to change this.'  I just wanted to see if it could be done at all.

Comment: Your edit and my comment crossed. Anyway, a text column is not searchable, not by a query, not by sproc. The OP should either carefully get the data by applying other criteria to other columns. Or change to (n)varchar.

Comment: I agree, but you can interrogate after the object is instantiated to a .NET generated T4 POCO object.  At least when I did SQL server 2014 instance, EF 6.1.3, and .NET 4.5.2 on my local system.  It is NOT the preferred solution I agree though.

Comment: Of course you can search in a `string`. Maybe I misinterpreted your "sql object".